# JDBC Insert Query Error

Tags: java, sql, jdbc

I'm new to Java and JDBC.. Currently I'm working on a school project for a Java course. I'm trying to pass some java variables to an Insert SQL query using JDBC, but I'm getting the follow exception:

```
SQLException: ORA-00917: missing comma
```

This is the instruction:

```
stmt.executeUpdate("INSERT INTO question (idnum, question, option1, option2, option3, option4, answer) VALUES("+4+", "+question+", "+option1+", "+option2+", "+option3+", "+option4+", "+answer+")");
```

Any ideas how to fix the query?

Comment: A) Use prepared statements. B) Your SQL has a syntax error. Print the string you're creating and see why.

Comment: You need to escape your input.

Answer (score 3):

First, the reason you are receiving an error is that you have a syntax error in your SQL. Simply printing the `String` you're creating would show you the problem.

That said, you should be using [prepared statements](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/sql/PreparedStatement.html). THere is simply *no* reason to construct the SQL manually. Not only does it avoid the problem you're having, it all but eliminates the chance your code is susceptible to SQL injection.

```
String query = "INSERT INTO question (idnum, question, option1, option2, option3, option4, answer) VALUES (?,?,?,?,?,?,?)";
PreparedStatement pstmt = conn.prepareStatement(query);
pstmt.setInt(1,4);
pstmt.setString(2,question);
// ... set all your params
pstmt.execute();
```

Answer (score 2):

Try this

```
String sql = 
   "INSERT INTO question (idnum, question, option1, option2, option3, option4, answer)       VALUES(?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)";
PreparedStatement preparedStatement = connection.prepareStatement(sql);

preparedStatement.setInt(1, 4);
preparedStatement.setString(2, question);
preparedStatement.setString(3, option1);
preparedStatement.setString(4, option2);
preparedStatement.setString(5, option3);
preparedStatement.setString(6, option4);
preparedStatement.setString(7, answer);

int rowsAffected = preparedStatement.executeUpdate();
```

Comment: Thanks Reimeus... This worked perfectly!!! I guess I need to start using PreparedStatements

Answer (score 1):

Change the double quotation`"`  to to a single quote `'` like this

```
String query = "INSERT INTO question (idnum,question) values 
 (4 , "'"+question+"'")";
```

Note that only string needs `'`, you can pass integers directly without using `'`, however, I prefer to use `PreparedStatement`, as it's much easier and very strong with SQL injections.

```
    PreparedStatement pr = conection.prepareStatement("insert into question(...) values(?,?,?,?...)");
    pr.setInt(1,4);
    pr.setString(2,"Some string");
//.....
 pr.executeUpdate();
```

Comment: I've removed my downvote now that you added the prepared statment. That said, I'd completely remove the first bit. There's simply no reason to manually construct the SQL and as demonstrated by the OP it's error-prone.

Comment: @BrianRoach: I agree with you, I usually solve the problem then I add extra information may be the best way(if I knew).

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
 stmt.executeUpdate("INSERT INTO question (idnum, question, option1, option2, option3, option4, answer) VALUES("+4+", '"+question+"', '"+option1+"', '"+option2+"', '"+option3+"', '"+option4+"', '"+answer+"')"
```